# How to declare & display my UITableView programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I re-update totally my question with all details for  more comprehension !

As they say pictures speak more than words, I made you a little mockup to explain everything in details!

First, i explain in text.

I have this :

- 1 MasterViewController = (RootViewController)
- 1 FirstView = UITableView (will be display many custom cells with data)
- 2 SecondView = UIView
- 3 ThirdView = UIView

Now image/mockup :

[image: my mockup for my problem]

In my MasterViewController.h (one part of code)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstView *firstView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondView *secondView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ThirdView *thirdView;
```

In my MasterViewController.m (one part of code)

```
        firstView = [[LastSalesView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, result.width, result.height)];
        firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        firstView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [bottomContainerView addSubview:firstView];
        [firstView setHidden:NO];

        secondView = [[LastSalesView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, result.width, result.height)];
        secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        secondView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [bottomContainerView addSubview:secondView];
        [secondView setHidden:NO];


        thirdView = [[LastSalesView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, result.width, result.height)];
        thirdView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        thirdView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [bottomContainerView addSubview:thirdView];
        [thirdView setHidden:NO];



-(void)viewFirstPage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button first pushed");
    [firstView setHidden:NO];
    [secondView setHidden:YES];
    [thirdView setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)viewSecondPage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button second pushed");
    [firstView setHidden:YES];
    [secondView setHidden:NO];
    [thirdView setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)viewThirdPage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button third pushed");
    [firstView setHidden:YES];
    [secondView setHidden:YES];
    [thirdView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Why did you subclass UITableView? I see no need for this.

Comment: I'm newbie and I do not understand too the meaning of your question! I tend to answer i need that I create my UITableView, right?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Your code certainly reflects that a newbie. There's too much wrong with it to really straighten it out effectively on here. That's ok, it comes with being a newbie. With time an perseverance, I believe you will learn. I suggest you work through this [UITableView tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/).

Comment: Do you have any introductory books? Are you new to programming?

Comment: Explain my errors here would be better ! 

The purpose of Stackoverflow is precisely to give the possibility to newbies like me to learn !

Your solution is to give me a link to a tutorial (that i will could find it myself with my friend google) is too simple for my taste and does not deserve any vote from me !

Sorry

Comment: To answer this question would be to write a tutorial on proper UITableView usage.

Comment: Or so,  just tell me where I made ​​mistakes and where put my code!!!

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is precisely _not_ for "newbies to learn"; it's for people to ask and answer focused, concrete questions about programming which can be answered completely here in a way that's relevant to future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your View UITableView then u can use use like this---

**MyFirstView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class UIViewController;

@interface MyFirstView : UITableView<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

**MyFirstView.m**

```
#import "MyFirstView.h"

@implementation MyFirstView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate=self;
        self.dataSource=self;
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *mycell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    if (mycell==nil) {
        mycell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    }

    mycell.textLabel.text=@"My super view is tableView.";
    return mycell;
}

@end
```

**Use these UITableView files as**

```
MyFirstView *tblView=[[MyFirstView alloc] init];
[tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];

[self.view addSubview:tblView];
```

If still do not understand [read this](http://developingios.blogspot.in/2013/02/uicombobox-for-iphone.html)

Comment: Many many many thanks for the response ! please check, i've totally re-update my question with more details !

Comment: Yes sure, i will do in instant but one precision, the FirstView is not a controller, just a simple UIView !

Comment: if it is UIView then just add @Class UIViewController; in header file.

Comment: i've re-updated my post check this code please

Comment: sometimes you are saying your first view is UIView and in question you are displaying firstview as UITableView.

Comment: so you busy with here ohh i see that @Herçules

Comment: I start my morning with 1 or two Q then start my other work @NitinGohel

Answer (score 1):

The `UITableViewDataSource` methods you're asking about generally belong in the view controller. In fact, your `MasterViewController` class already declares that it implements the  `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

So, when you create your table view in `MasterViewController`, the view controller will need to tell the table view that it is the data source (and delegate):

```
myTableView = [[MyTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, result.width, result.height)];
myTableView.dataSource = self;
myTableView.delegate = self;
```

This should get you on the right path.

Comment: ok thanks, could do it directly in my MyTableView.h and MyTableView.m?

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. It goes against the MVC pattern, since it would imply that the view knows how to retrieve data, which is task for a controller-type class. If you want to keep your code neat, I can give you an advice, but it would probably be too long for commenting it

Comment: Ok thanks ! I update my post with the new code i've implemented and works but as you say the code must be bad I think!

Comment: You will do yourself a world of good by watching this [introduction to the MVC design pattern](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/1.-mvc-introduction-to-objective/id473757255?i=105952318&mt=2) on iOS by Paul Hegarty (watch the whole series, actually).

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer*** This answer was given before OP updated his post, the original question was pretty much "how do I use table views?", now it has morphed into something totally different. My answer may still be valuable to someone.

Let me explain to you, briefly, how table views should be used. There's three main components here:

1. `UITableView` is the **view** in the MVC pattern, its only job is to present the data, and do it so relative to its content offset, and it does so by having a set amount of cells that it enqueues when they go out of the screen, and dequeues them when they should be shown. If you pay attention, the `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so all it does, is extend the scrolling mechanism by having a reusable cell system that allows it to use a minimal amount of cells.
2. `UITableViewCell` is responsible for representing a single piece of data within an app. It's also part of the **view** in the MVC pattern.
3. Now, a `UITableView` needs to get its data from somewhere, there's two possibilities, either you:

   1. Subclass a `UITableViewController`.
   2. Have another class fill-in the data by conforming to `UITableViewDataSource`.

Either choice you pick, the class that now will fill-in the data will become the **controller** in the MVC pattern (The model is entirely up to you, could be a simple array of strings, as much as the table view cares).

The `UITableView` expects cells to be filled (or created) for him. Here's an important distinction:

- In iOS 4.x and previous, you had to write your own cell creation, which is kinda odd, since it would go against the MVC pattern.
- in iOS 5 the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` and `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` methods were introduced, and you no longer need to create your own cell creation, it automatically checks if it needs more cells, and it instantiates them as needed.

All things said, you should never have to subclass the table view if you only need to change the data it will display.

### To answer your question...

#### Using Nibs

It's entirely up to you on who you think should be the delegate, you could even have a separate object controlling the data within the tableview.

But for now, let's make it run in `MasterViewController`. In your `MasterViewController` xib file, have a normal UITableView without subclassing. Make sure `MasterViewController` conforms to `<UITableViewDataSource>` and then connect the tableview `dataSource` outlet to `MasterViewController` (the File Owner's, most likely).

The only two methods that matter are `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, implement those, and your tableView shall work.

The other things like height, editing and everything else, are part of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, if you care about those, repeat the above steps but for the `delegate` outlet.

#### By Code

I don't get why people hate nibs so much, but.. whatever, let's make it run on the `MasterViewController`.

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#include "MasterViewController.h"
#include "MyCell.h"

@interface MasterViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,weak) UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Notice that this method only gets called if you're using a nib
    // If you plan of getting rid of nibs ENTIRELY, use -loadView
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate   = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    // Save a reference to it
    self.tableView = tableView;

    // iOS 5+
    [tableView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell.something"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Again, iOS 5+
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell.something" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello world!";        

    return cell;
}

@end
```

### Tip for complex views

Also, I'm under the impression that you don't want the `MasterViewController` to handle the code related to the data of the table view. Since it's a delegate, you can point it to whatever you want! Drop an `NSObject` that conform to the protocols mentioned, and you can simply do this:

[image: Hot IBOutlet action]

Very useful if you're dealing with a very complex view, and having all that extra `tableView:didFart:andSmelledNice:` code gets in the way. You obviously do it by code, but I won't put that, consider it your punishment for going away from the way of the nib.

Comment: Waouhhhhhh, this, IS the response !!!! Many many many thanks for the response ! please check, i've totally re-update my question with more details !

Comment: @GilbertOOl Gilbert, this is the third time you update your question, and each time you ask something different. Part of the idea of SO is that when an issue is answered, you solve it, close it, and then, if you have another doubt, post another question. The question has changed so damn much that no answers make sense now. Your original question seemed to aim on how to just make UITableViews, now you want us to build an specific layout.

Comment: No, sorry, the problem remains the same, it concerns only the UITableView as departing!

The only thing that have changed, that i forget to specify that the UITableView is not filled all the screen but this part of code is my problem!